# How does this python function get its parameters?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-models

I'm implementing amazon S3 into my django application, following this tutorial:
http://djangotricks.blogspot.com/2013/12/how-to-store-your-media-files-in-amazon.html

In it, he defines a function upload_avatar_to which takes two parameters:

```
def upload_avatar_to(instance, filename):
    import os
    from django.utils.timezone import now
    filename_base, filename_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return 'profiles/%s%s' % (
        now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S"),
        filename_ext.lower(),
    )
```

However, when he calls it, he supplies no parameters:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    # ...
    avatar = models.ImageField(_("Avatar"), upload_to=upload_avatar_to, blank=True)
    # ...
```

How does the function get instance and filename if it wasn't supplied when called?

I want to add an extra parameter to the function call, say "foldername". How can I do that?

Comment: The `upload_avatar_to` function must be called from the `ImageField` constructor. Can you look at that?

Comment: He's not calling the function, he is passing the function object to `models.ImageField()`, which might call it or it might store it to call it later.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly documented in Django documentation, upload_to can be a callable:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

According the official documentation:

This may also be a callable, such as a function, which will be called to obtain the upload path, including the filename. **This callable must be able to accept two arguments, and return a Unix-style path** (with forward slashes) to be passed along to the storage system. The two arguments that will be passed are:

**instance**
An instance of the model where the FileField is defined. More specifically, this is the particular instance where the current file is being attached.

***In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field.***

**filename**
The filename that was originally given to the file. This may or may not be taken into account when determining the final destination path.

Comment: This link may answer the question but it would be better to include an explanation as to why in the answer. Link only answers can be broken by changing links. Please consider editing it.

Comment: No problem I shall do, I just believe that questions relating to already clearly documented answers is just typing again what is easily readable at the source. Nevertheless I shall append the answer of the documentation in terms of link failure.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like a call of the function upload_avatar_to() but rather passing a the function itself as a parameter so it can be called inside of avatar.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that Django is being passed the function object itself in that last line of code - the function isn't being called at that time. That function will later be called inside the `ImageField` constructor, where it will be given the `instance` and `filename` arguments and return a value. This is easy to do since functions are first-class objects in Python.

As petkostas showed in his link, the function you provide must take exactly two arguments, instance and filename. We can work around this, though!

What you could do is create a function wrapper for `upload_avatar_to`, which will allow you to supply that extra parameter while still conforming to the Django requirements. Check this out:

```
def upload_to_wrapper(foldername):
  def wrapper(instance, filename):
    upload_avatar_to(instance, filename, foldername)
  return wrapper
```

Then you would define your function like this:

```
def upload_avatar_to(instance, filename, foldername):
  # Do your thing.
```

And finally, this is the last line you would call, and the point where you supply the `foldername` you want:

```
avatar = models.ImageField(_("Avatar"), upload_to=upload_to_wrapper(foldername), blank=True)
```

Essentially, `upload_to_wrapper` returns a modified version of the `upload_avatar_to` object, which has the `foldername` already supplied, and only `instance` and `filename` need to be specified. This allows you to work around the Django requirements. That particular `ImageField` function requires you to supply a function object that takes `instance` and `filename`, but that's exactly what `upload_to_wrapper` returns, so you're good to go.